# How to include weight in edge of graph?

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, jgrapht

I want to include weights or costs of the edge on my graph using this jgrapht interface-class:

```
package org.jgrapht;

public interface WeightedGraph<V extends Object, E extends Object> extends Graph<V, E> {

    public static final double DEFAULT_EDGE_WEIGHT = 1.0;

    public void setEdgeWeight(E e, double d);
}
```

Comment: it's an interface. you need a file that implements it to have a field weight, and change it whenever

Answer (score 20):

Yo have described `Interface WeightedGraph<V,E>` from [here](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/WeightedGraph.html#setEdgeWeight%28E,double%29).

You need to use `SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph` to set the weights of its edges.
Look at this example, it creates [Directed Weighted Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) by using  `graph.addVertex()`, `graph.setEdgeWeight()` methods and considers
shortest path between some edges by using [Dijkstra Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) implemented in `DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween()` method.

```
    import org.jgrapht.*;
    import org.jgrapht.alg.*;
    import org.jgrapht.graph.*;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Graph {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

            SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>  graph = 
            new SimpleDirectedWeightedGraph<String, DefaultWeightedEdge>
            (DefaultWeightedEdge.class); 
            graph.addVertex("vertex1");
            graph.addVertex("vertex2");
            graph.addVertex("vertex3");
            graph.addVertex("vertex4");
            graph.addVertex("vertex5");


            DefaultWeightedEdge e1 = graph.addEdge("vertex1", "vertex2"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e1, 5); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e2 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex3"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e2, 3); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e3 = graph.addEdge("vertex4", "vertex5"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e3, 6); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e4 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex4"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e4, 2); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e5 = graph.addEdge("vertex5", "vertex4"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e5, 4); 


            DefaultWeightedEdge e6 = graph.addEdge("vertex2", "vertex5"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e6, 9); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e7 = graph.addEdge("vertex4", "vertex1"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e7, 7); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e8 = graph.addEdge("vertex3", "vertex2"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e8, 2); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e9 = graph.addEdge("vertex1", "vertex3"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e9, 10); 

            DefaultWeightedEdge e10 = graph.addEdge("vertex3", "vertex5"); 
            graph.setEdgeWeight(e10, 1); 


            System.out.println("Shortest path from vertex1 to vertex5:");
            List shortest_path =   DijkstraShortestPath.findPathBetween(graph, "vertex1", "vertex5");
            System.out.println(shortest_path);

        }
    }
```