# How to change the criteria of the Dijkstra algotithm when trying to find the shortest path?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra, jgrapht

I am working with a undirected graph which relates some places to have fun in an amusement park. Each vertex is a place and each node gives us the distance and the average time between two places.

How do I change the criteria of the algorithm to decide which edge is shorter, for instance, instead of comparing the edges by distance, comparing them by the avgTime. I have a Graph<Place, Vecinity> where the type Vecinity has two attributes, distance and avgTime between two places.

Here is some of my code:

`public static List<Place> exercise2a(Graph<Place,Vecinity> g, Place p1, Place p2) { var alg = new DijkstraShortestPath<Place, Vecinity>(g); return alg.getPath(p1, p2).getVertexList(); }`

[amusement park](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Isx.png)

This method returns the list of places that belong to the shortest path in terms of distance (although i did not specify it), but i want it also in terms of avgTime.

I want first to apply the algorithm according to the distance attribute and then apply it again according to the avgTime attribute.

I am using the Dijkstra algorithm of the library: `org.jgrapht.alg.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath` of [JGraphT](https://jgrapht.org/).

Specific documentation: [Documentation](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/shortestpath/DijkstraShortestPath.html)

Comment: Did you code the algorithm yourself, or are you using a library?  For library, check library docs.  If your own code then you can modify the line which gets the distance.

Comment: @ravenspoint I am using the algortihm of the following library: org.jgrapht.alg.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath. I tried to find the solution in the documentation but i did not find anything. However, i thought about casting the Graph<Place, Vecinity> into Graph<Place, Double ("distance")> and Graph<Place, Double ("avgTime") respectively. Any suggestion?

Comment: Just add a flag to your algorithm which criteria to use.

Comment: There is a lack of details in your question. So, unless / until you edit your question, we can only guess. Here are some resources that can help you understand [How to Write A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/), the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), with links on those pages.

Comment: I have added a link to the library and the library tag to your question.  In future, do this work yourself BEFORE posting your questions.

Comment: @ravenspoint Sorry I got confused with the translations. I intended to write undirected, which means that all edges are undirected, that is, there is no specific direction you have to follow in some edge. On the other hand, in a directed graph each edge has its corresponding direction to follow.

Comment: Needs more code; how does the amusement park get into the programme?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246409/how-to-include-weight-in-edge-of-graph You can set the weight of an edge when you build your graph.

Comment: @RaffleBuffle If I understand the question properly, the graph is already built, but each edge has *two* weights. The O/P wants to know how to specify which weight is to be used when the shortest path method is run. This is an example of why questions of this type should include more code.

Comment: Please show more code. I suspect it would help us if we could see relevant parts of the `Vecinity` class.